# Passing an array of Components as a Props in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for a way to pass an array of components to a prop for a tabbing component. Just wondering if that's possible.

So I need to create a component that will shorten material ui's tabbing method but I cannot find a way to pass an array of components as a prop so that it will be rendered on that component.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<FullWidthTab
components = [<Component1/>, <Component2/>] //this is where components renders
 menuLabels = ['Menu1', 'Menu2'] //this is where title render
/>
```

And I map them on my code like this and I used lodash map method:

```
map(components, component=>{

 <TabContainer>{component}</TabContainer>

}
```

But it returns this.
Warning: react-swipeable-view: one of the children provided is invalid: null.
We are expecting a valid React Element

And when I `console.log` the component it returns:
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: ƒ, key: null, ref: null, props: {…}} Object Need help

I hope it can render the components.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Component's name must be started with a capital letter, but I can see here `components = [<component1/>, <component2/>]` they were not. So you must convert `[<component1/>, <component2/>]` to `[<Component1/>, <Component2/>]`. Second thing I see your `map` syntax is strange, it must be like this:

```
components.map(component => (<TabContainer>{component}</TabContainer>))
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: Thanks but still not working, BTW I used lodash's map method I edited my post already

Answer (score 1):

I solved This with another implementation.

I used 'react-swipeable-views' and instead passing a component I used this

```
       <SwipeableViews
            axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
            index={this.state.value}
            onChangeIndex={this.handleChangeIndex}
        >
            { children }
        </SwipeableViews>
```

And Changed:

```
<FullWidthTab
components = [<Component1/>, <Component2/>] //this is where components renders
 menuLabels = ['Menu1', 'Menu2'] //this is where title render
/>
```

To

```
<FullWidthTab
 components = [<Component1/>, <Component2/>] //this is where components renders
 menuLabels = ['Menu1', 'Menu2'] //this is where title render
>
  <Component1/>
  <Component2/>
</FullWidthTab>
```

But if you can get how to pass components via props that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Cause you need return a value in map.

```
map(components, component=>{

 return <TabContainer>{component}</TabContainer>

}
```

Comment: I did this inside the render of the component. Return can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Your es6 syntax needs a subtle adjustment to return the react component.

```
map(components, component => <TabContainer>{component}</TabContainer> )
```

or, if you can use the map function from your array instead of importing from a library.

```
components.map( component => <TabContainer>{component}</TabContainer> )
```

Comment: Ohh I forgot I used map of lodash